# аргументы для функции main()

Tags: linux, c, unix

До сегодняшнего дня писал программы на Си с таким применением функции main: `int main(void)`. Но сегодня решил расширить свой кругозор и написал уже такую функцию: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Тут передача аргументов согласно статье в которой я это вычитал работала как положено.

Я решил проверить как будет работать программа если я попытаюсь передать каждый аргумет по отдельности. Вот что получилось:

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* first_arg, char* name, char* name1) {
    printf("Argument:\n%s\n%s\n%s", first_arg ,name, name);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат на вызов `./start.out некоторая строка здесь`:

```
Argument:
~�&{�
��&{�
��&{�
```

Теперь то же самое только с массивами аргументов.

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* first_arg[1], char* name[1], char* name1[1]) {
    printf("Argument:\n%s\n%s\n%s", first_arg[1] ,name[1], name[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат на вызов `./start.out некоторая строка здесь`:

```
Argument:
некоторая
SESSION_MANAGER=local/reiji-Legion-5-15IMH6:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2497,unix/reiji-Legion-5-15IMH6:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2497
SESSION_MANAGER=local/reiji-Legion-5-15IMH6:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2497,unix/reiji-Legion-5-15IMH6:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2497
```

Почему программа в формате `char* argv[]` принимает аргументы правильно, но если я разделю принятие аргументов на две отдельные переменные типа `char* argv1` и `char* argv2` - то аргументы я уже не получу?

Откуда берется `SESSION_MANAGER=local/reiji-Legion-5-15IMH6:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2497,unix/reiji-Legion-5-15IMH6:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2497` и что это вообще такое?

Как отлаживать подобного рода программы - ведь отладчик запускает отлаживаемую программу без аргументов?

Comment: Вам надо посмотреть вглубь, понять как именно на уровне машинного кода передаются аргументы. В современных 64-бит процессорах (по крайней мере в самых распространенных) они передаются в регистрах с предопределенными номерами (это называется "соглашение о связях" или ABI (или еще как)). Например, первай аргумент передается в R0, второй в  R1 и т.д. В нашем случае OS при запуске программы  в R0 передает количество аргументов командной строки, а в R1 адрес памяти (начало массива указателей) c адресами строк (каждая строка это передаваемый аргумент командной строки. А нулевой - это имя программы

Comment: См. в вике  [Соглашение о вызове](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5) и [Двоичный интерфейс приложений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: *`"Откуда берется SESSION_MANAGER= ...  и что это вообще такое?"`*. Это первый элемент массива environment переменных. Можете посмотреть на них, выполнив команду `env` в терминале. Указатель на него передается в 3-м параметре main. (в общем случае у main вот такой прототип -- `int main (int argc, char **argv, char **environ)`). Вообще,  если хотите правильно работать с интерфейсом командной строки, то советую почитать [отсюда и вглубь](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Basics.html) по всем ссылкам.

Comment: @avp Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте позапускать с разными аргументами командной строки такую программку:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i ,argv[i]);
}
```

Это многое для вас прояснит... Передается массив указателей, а это совсем не то же самое, что набор параметров типа `char*`!

Фактически первый же вам аргумент оказывается указателем не на строку, а на массив указателей — этого достаточно, чтобы понять, что так, как вы, действовать нельзя?

А вообще в стандарте не указано, как именно должны передаваться аргументы в функцию, так что действуйте просто по <s>уставу</s>стандарту, и все будет нормально работать. Кстати, совершенно не понимаю, зачем — чего вы хотите добиться таким способом, чем он лучше стандартного (если бы работал)?

Что до отладчика — то нормальный отладчик позволяет указать параметры командной строки...

Comment: это к сожалению уже сделал из описания в статье https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8 - но полной картины это так и не показало - как это работает изнутри и где взять на эту тему информацию именно эти вопросы меня терзают

Comment: `Фактически первый же вам аргумент оказывается указателем не на строку, а на массив указателей ` - то есть если в моем случае аргумент0 это `./start.out` - то это и есть имя массива указателей на аргументы?

Comment: Имя массива - это имя аргумента. Или вы о чем? Нулевой аргумент - *обычно* имя самой программы.